# Loop Infinito. Como parar o Loop em uma determinada situação?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiz a implementação do código abaixo, ele roda a página a cada X Segundos, porém ele nunca para, fica em um loop infinito.

Gostaria de fazer o código parar de executar, quando:

`if (track_click >= total_pages - 1) {}`

Porém não sei qual código colocar para parar a execução do script.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var track_click = 0; 
    var total_pages = <?php echo $total_pages; ?>;

    $('#animation_image').load("exportar_4_detalhe.php", {'page': track_click}, function() {
        track_click++;
    });

    var funcaoCounter = 0;
    var funcaoTimer = setInterval(function(){
        funcaoCounter++;

            $('.load_more').hide();
            $('.animation_image').show(); 



            if (track_click <= total_pages){

                $.post('exportar_4_detalhe.php', {'page': track_click}, function(data) {

                    $(".load_more").hide();

                    $("#results").append(data);

                    var resultado = ( track_click /total_pages ) * 100;
                    // document.title = track_click + " de " + total_pages;

                    var new_num = resultado.toFixed(2);

                    var new_num = new_num + "%";

                    document.title = new_num;

                    $('.porcentagem').text(new_num);

                    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#animation_image").offset().top}, 500);

                    $('.animation_image').hide();

                    track_click++;

                }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(thrownError); 
                    $(".load_more").show();
                    $('.animation_image').hide(); 
                });


                if (track_click >= total_pages - 1)
                {
                     $('.animation_image').hide(); 
                     clearInterval(funcaoTimer);
                     alert('Todos os Registros forma Exibidos!');

                }
            }

}, 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: Já tem uma linha no seu código que faz isso: `clearInterval(funcaoTimer);`. Porém não olhei o código em detalhes, então não sei dizer se isto está sendo usado no lugar certo.

Comment: O pior que vi isso, pra mim está no lugar certo, porém não funcionou, tem como me ajudar ?

Comment: Eu inseri assim:  clearInterval(funcaoTimer);, porém o código continua funcionando após eu pedi para interromper...

Comment: Talvez o lugar correto para colocar isso (aliás, todo o `if (track_click >= total_pages - 1)`) seja logo após o `track_click++;` que tem dentro do callback do `$.post`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retire a condição:

```
if (track_click >= total_pages - 1)
```

de **dentro** da condição:

```
if (track_click <= total_pages){
```

Se esse fosse um programa **síncrono**, estaria tudo bem, mas como ele é assíncrono é possível que o `track_click` seja incrementado **duas vezes** entre uma invocação da função e outra - fazendo com que o `if` interno jamais seja executado. Isso deve corrigir o problema do loop infinito, *entretanto* eu tenho uma forte suspeita que seu código tem mais problemas que isso:

- Sua linha `$('#animation_image').load("exportar_4_detalhe.php", ...` executa com `track_click` igual a zero, e ao final incrementa-o para um.

  - Se isso ocorrer em menos de 1 segundo, a primeira invocação da `funcaoTimer` vai requisitar a página `1`; caso contrário, ela vai requisitar a página `0`!
  - Pior: se a primeira requisição levar mais de 1 e menos de 2 segundos, e a segunda levar *menos* de 1 segundo, a `funcaoTimer` vai pedir a página `0`, e em seguida a página `2` (ela nunca vai pedir a `1`).
- Em qualquer situação que o `post` levar mais de um segundo para completar, o `setInterval` fará com que ele seja tentado de novo, **com a mesma página**; isso significa que a mesma página pode ser atualizada duas vezes, provocando uma condição de corrida (i.e. ainda que a página fique ok, o `track_click` será incrementado duas vezes, saltando uma página tal como no caso anterior).

Seu código *precisa* ser refatorado, e eu tenho algumas sugestões para fazê-lo. Supondo (como estabelecido nos comentário) que as páginas devem ser buscadas na ordem, e que não é necessário esperar 1 segundo entre uma e outra, um meio viável seria fazer a requisição à página N no próprio *callback* da página N-1. Exemplo:

```
var track_click = 0; 
var total_pages = <?php echo $total_pages; ?>;

$('#animation_image').load("exportar_4_detalhe.php", {'page': track_click}, function() {
    track_click++;
    proximaPagina();
});

function proximaPagina() {
    $('.load_more').hide();
    $('.animation_image').show();

    if (track_click <= total_pages){ // Nota: "<=" ou "<"?

        $.post('exportar_4_detalhe.php', {'page': track_click}, function(data) {

            $(".load_more").hide();
            $("#results").append(data);

            var resultado = ( track_click /total_pages ) * 100;
            // document.title = track_click + " de " + total_pages;

            var new_num = resultado.toFixed(2);
            var new_num = new_num + "%";
            document.title = new_num;
            $('.porcentagem').text(new_num);

            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#animation_image").offset().top}, 500);
            $('.animation_image').hide();

            track_click++;
            proximaPagina(); // Chama de novo pra próxima página, ou para concluir

        }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError); 
            $(".load_more").show();
            $('.animation_image').hide(); 

            // POSSIBILIDADE: tentar de novo após 1s quando houver falha
            // (descomente para habilitar)
            // setTimeout(proximaPagina, 1000); // Tenta de novo a mesma página
        });
    }
    else {
        $('.animation_image').hide(); 
        alert('Todos os Registros forma Exibidos!');
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado,  pela grande ajuda... Tem interesse em melhorar esse código pra mim?  totalsite@outlook.com

Comment: @DaniloRamon Desculpe, não entendi o que você quer dizer. Eu me ofereci para editar minha resposta acrescentando uma sugestão de refatoração, mas para isso eu preciso desses detalhes que eu perguntei. Pois há diversas maneiras de fazer isso, cada uma com seus prós e contras (ex.: disparar cada requisição no *callback* da anterior; disparar várias requisições simultaneamente, mas com *throttling*; manter a lógica mais ou menos como está, porém eliminando a condição de corrida).

Comment: Gostaria de saber quanto vc cobraria para acertar o codigo

Comment: Alinho por email com vc...  totalsite@outlook.com

Comment: Amigo,  pode entrar em contato comigo pelo email totalsite@outlook.com? Teria como?

Comment: Uou, devagar aí! :) Se você quer uma mãozinha pra resolver esse problema em particular, eu faço isso aqui nessa resposta mesmo, de graça... Mas se é algo mais complexo, lamento mas eu não presto esse tipo de serviço.

Comment: Amigo, o que preciso é implementar esse código, para somente para conforme sua sugestão mesmo: Eu preciso a página N só seja requisitada depois que a N-1 estiver pronta, ou seja a página foi exibida com sucesso, ai sim ele pode requisitar a página subsequente. Desde já agradeço pela ajuda...

Comment: @DaniloRamon Blz, estou saindo pra almoçar agora, na volta atualizo a resposta com minha sugestão. Mas e quanto ao tempo da requisição, precisa mesmo esperar 1 segundo entre uma e outra, ou pode-se começar a N tão logo a N-1 chegou?

Comment: Isso, mesmo... acho até melhor mesmo...rs

Comment: @DaniloRamon Aí está! Assumi qua a primeira página é `0` e a última página é `total_pages`. Se isso estiver incorreto (ex.: se a última página for `total_pages - 1`)  mude a condição de parada (o `if` em `proximaPagina`). Além disso, quando há erro na requisição você tem duas opções: 1) Não fazer nada; 2) Tentar de novo a mesma página após 1 segundo. Veja o comentário dentro da parte com `fail`.

Comment: Tem como mostrar para mim no código, pois conheço php, mais java sou leigo mesmo.

Comment: 1) Esse `if (track_click <= total_pages){` vai entrar se `track_click` for igual a `total_pages` - fazendo uma requisição pra essa página. Se a última página for `total_pages - 1`, troque o `<=` por `<`. 2) Descomente `setTimeout(proximaPagina, 1000);` caso você queira tentar de novo uma requisição com falha, após 1 segundo (cuidado, pois se ela falhar repetidamente, vai mostrar um `alert` por segundo!).

Comment: podemos nos falar por skype, e depois postamos a resolução aqui. Pode ser a noite em um horário melhor para vc ? Pode ser assim ?

Comment: Se você tem mais dúvidas, ou abra uma pergunta separada ou pergunte no [chat]. Sinto muito não poder dar mais atenção ao seu problema, mas tem mais gente precisando de ajuda, e eu sou só um voluntário aqui, dentre muitos...

Comment: Acertei o código, agora ficou somente outra dúvida, que não entendi bem no comentário, não por tempo. [link]http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55050/n%C3%A3o-executar-script-por-tempo-e-sim-por-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-script[/link]